# Changing the name of a folder in a /midia older?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

Hey guys I have this very ugly name in a hdd and i would love to change it :
/media/usr/44691167-b916-42ad-87f0-b215c6ef2e6c$.

May i had write wrong, the hdd name is '44691167-b916-42ad-87f0-b215c6ef2e6c'. Sorry, my mistake.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the `$`, otherwise the shell expects a variable.

`cd /media/usr ; mv '44691167-b916-42ad-87f0-b215c6ef2e6c$.' whateveryouwant`

should do the trick.

Comment: Hey Falk I tried but I failed. My mistake because I don't have clarified that that ugly name is the name of the hdd. :(

Comment: Then it's the UUID of the file system and can't be changed. Is the HDD mounted to this folder? (`mount | grep 4469` should give this away)